# Condicionar un link para que redirija

Tags: javascript, html5

como se puede condicionar un link?

es decir si se cumple una condicion que recien se redirija al url del link, en caso contrario no.

```js
if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
console.log("SI deberia funcionar el link");
}else{
console.log("NO deberia funcionar el link");

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/miLink"> link
<input type="checkbox" id="miCheck">
```

en este caso que planteo, el marcado del check seria la condicion para que se pueda habilitar el link

Comment: Tú mismo te has dado la respuesta: *si se cumple una condición*. Entonces, lo único que tienes que hacer es un `if`.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía edite mi pregunta, revisalo porfavor

Comment: Si la cuestion es que le de al checkbox puedes hacer que aparezca el link usando los métodos de jquery de hide y show $('a').show(); tendrías que poner tu elemento en un inicio con css display:none y usas la mísma lógica que tienes en tu código.

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta de acuerdo a tu edición.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo quieres **deshabilitar** un link dependiendo del estado del checkbox. Hay varias formas, una es quitando el `href` al link:

```js
if ($('#miCheck').is(":checked")) {
  $('#link').attr('href', 'https://es.stackoverflow.com');
} else {
  $('#link').attr('href', 'javascript:void(0)');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com" id="link" disabled>Inicio</a>
<input type="checkbox" id="miCheck" checked>
```

Otra forma es usando una clase que *simule* que el link está desactivado:

```js
$('#miCheck').on('change', function () {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $('#link').removeClass('disabled');
  } else {
    $('#link').addClass('disabled');
  }
});

/* Para que evalúe al cargar el documento */
if ($('#miCheck').is(":checked")) {
  $('#link').removeClass('disabled');
} else {
  $('#link').addClass('disabled');
}
```

```css
.disabled {
  color: #ddd;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com" id="link" disabled>Inicio</a>
<input type="checkbox" id="miCheck">
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer la validación de esta manera.

```js
$('#miCheck').on('click', function(){
if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
 $('a').show()
}else{
  $('a').hide()
console.log("NO deberia funcionar el link");

}

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="link" style="display:none" href="/miLink"> link </a>
<input type="checkbox" id="miCheck">
```